# Matplotlib and Pandas Package Install and Maintenance

Tags: python

I need help.

I just recently installed the matplotlib and pandas packages into python in virtual studio code for data science.

For some reason, after installing them into my terminal, both packages have stopped importing into my script . Every time I try to import them in the file, I'm given a problem message saying: unable to import 'matplotlib.pyplot' pylint(import-error). The problem section of the terminal also gives me the error message saying: ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'pandas'

I have already installed both packages into my terminal. I know this because every time I type in pip install matplotlib into the terminal, it returns with:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in

c:\users\janse\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)

Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\janse\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)

Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\janse\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib) (1.14.
```

Thank you for helping me out, I have looked online and can't seem to find an answer to this issue.

Comment: That might be related to an environment error. Are you using python3 ? Can you update your question with the outputs of `which python`, `which pip` and `python --version` ?

Answer (score 0):

try installing pandas and matplotlib in the terminal of Visual Studio Code using pip as-

```
pip install pandas
pip install matplotlib
```

I think it should work after that.
Hope my answer helped you.